# Can I send slash commands by Google Chat API REST?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-hangouts, google-chat

I would like to know if it is possible to send slash commands through the Google Chat REST API. When I send for example `/random pokemon` to the Giphy app, the command /random is interpreted as a plain text and doesnt trigger any action back from the app.

I'm trying to create the message using the endpoint from [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create) `POST [https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=spaces/*}/messages](https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/%7Bparent=spaces/*%7D/messages)

Am I missing something or is there no option to send these commands through the API? The thing is, if commands can't be sent, I don't know how to interact with my implementation...

That's all. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not fully familiar with your concern but It seems possible to send `slash commands` through chat REST API but it depends on how your app is designed and implemented. You have to configure it properly, follow the official documentation: [Respond to slash commands as a Google Chat app](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/slash-commands)